# По наведению на ссылку менять цвет курсора

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как по наведению на ссылку менять цвет курсора? По одной ссылке без проблем а вот когда их много, непонятно...

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  
const cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');
const hover = document.querySelectorAll('.link');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (evt) => {
  cursor.style = `top: ${evt.pageY}px; left: ${evt.pageX}px`;
  
  hover.forEach((item, i) => {
    const target = evt.target;

    if (item === target) {
    cursor.style.background = 'red';
  } else {
    cursor.style.background = '';
  }
  });
});
});
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}

#cursor {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

a {
  display:block;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href='#'>Ссылка 1</a>
<a class="link" href='#'>Ссылка 2</a>
<p>Text</p>
<div id="cursor"></div>
```

Comment: Использовать css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто проверять наличие класса `link` у `evt.target`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  
  const cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', (evt) => {
    cursor.style = `top: ${evt.pageY}px; left: ${evt.pageX}px`;
    cursor.style.background = evt.target.classList.contains('link') ? 'red' : '';
  });
  
});
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}

#cursor {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

a {
  display:block;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href='#'>Ссылка 1</a>
<a class="link" href='#'>Ссылка 2</a>
<p>Text</p>
<div id="cursor"></div>
```

*upd.* то же самое на css (не всегда работает, в отличии от js):

```
.link:hover ~ #cursor {
  background: red;
}
```